# How do I limit org-sparse-tree to a subtree?

Tags: org-mode

I want to see only the TODOs in a subtree, but calling `org-sparse-tree` then `t` shows TODOs *in the whole buffer*.

How do I limit the sparse filtering behavior to the subtree under the item at point?

Comment: One option might be to use `C-x n s` (`org-narrow-to-subtree`).

Comment: That works, thanks! I will accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `org-narrow-to-subtree`, which is bound to `C-x n s` by default.

This is not specific to sparse trees but can be used whenever you want to focus on a specific subtree in your org file.

Comment: And is there any way of limiting a sparse tree to a subtree without having to narrow and hide the rest in the buffer first?